# How can i send an hex over spp bluetooth

Tags: java, android

I want to send this hex message over Bluetooth

```
0x45, 0x02, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x54
```

I use this method to convert from string to byte:

```
 public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

To send it over bluetooth:

```
btSocket.getOutputStream().write(hexStringToByteArray("4502020000030000000054"));
```

But do not revive anything on other Bluetooth module.
What i do it wrong?

Comment: We don't see you flushing or closing the stream or closing the socket. Nor don't we see your receiving code. So how should we know?

Comment: It is correct how i do converting?

Comment: You should also write a byteArrayToHexString function to check if `data` contains the right bytes.

Comment: "It is correct how i do converting?" -> write a unit test to check.

Comment: are you using UTF-8 for your string? As per the default in android?

If so, your bugger is only half the length of the string passed to it.